# Como mostrar el formato dd/mm/aaaa en java dentro de una tabla?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, date

Tengo el siguiente codigo que me trae el mes y el año actual

```html
// Obtienes el mes actual 
mes = LocalDate.now().getMonth().getValue(); 

//Se obtiene el año actual 
Year año = Year.now();
annio = año.getValue();
```

Tengo este metodo

```
 public List<Integer> llenaDiasAnioMes() {

    List<Integer> lDias = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= this.getLongitudMes(); i++) {
        lDias.add(i);
        lDias.add(mes);
        lDias.add(annio);
    }
    return lDias;

}
```

y me arroja en consola lo siguiente

```html
LISTA DIAS[1, 2, 2018, 2, 2, 2018, 3, 2, 2018, 4, 2, 2018, 5, 2, 2018, 6, 2, 2018, 7, 2, 2018, 8, 2, 2018, 9, 2, 2018, 10, 2, 2018, 11, 2, 2018, 12, 2, 2018, 13, 2, 2018, 14, 2, 2018, 15, 2, 2018, 16, 2, 2018, 17, 2, 2018, 18, 2, 2018, 19, 2, 2018, 20,
2, 2018, 21, 2, 2018, 22, 2, 2018, 23, 2, 2018, 24, 2, 2018, 25, 2, 2018, 26, 2, 2018, 27, 2, 2018, 28, 2, 2018]
```

Me muestra todos los dias del mes de febrero (28), con el mes y el año actual

Ahora, lo que quiero hacer es pasar esos datos a una tabla
que se vean de la siguiente manera, que en la columna de fecha aparezcan todos los dias del mes con el año actual , de esta forma 23/02/2018, y asi si cambia de mes, que cambie los dias correspondientes a ese mes
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo mi tabla de esta manera

```html
<p:dataTable id="detalle" var="detalle" styleClass="columns" value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.incidenciaAnioMesDet}" emptyMessage="No se encontraron registros.">

  <p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>

      <p:column headerText="FECHA" style="width:20px;" styleClass="columns" />
      <p:column headerText="ENTRADA" style="width:20px;" styleClass="columns" />
      <p:column headerText="SALIDA" style="width:20px;" styleClass="columns" />
      <p:column headerText="INCIDENCIA" style="width:60px;" styleClass="columns" />
      <p:column headerText="ACCION" style="width:10px;" styleClass="columns" />
    </p:row>
  </p:columnGroup>
  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.llenaDiasAnioMes()}" />
  </p:column>

  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText value="#{detalle.horaEntrada}">
      <f:convertDateTime type="date" timeZone="CST" pattern="HH:mm:ss" />
    </h:outputText>

  </p:column>
  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText value="#{detalle.horaSalida}">
      <f:convertDateTime type="date" timeZone="CST" pattern="HH:mm:ss" />
    </h:outputText>
  </p:column>
  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText value="#{detalle.incidencias.cveIdIncidencia}  #{detalle.incidencias.concepto}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" title="View" onclick="PF('modalIntentos').show();">
    </p:commandButton>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

y en la primer columna mando a llamar el metodo que me regresa los dias con el mes y con el año, pero me los muestra de esta forma
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como le puedo hacer para pintar por fila los dias del mes, asi como en la imagen?
o que otra forma puedo obtener todos los dias del mes y mostrarlos en ese formato

Comment: Posible duplicado de [como obtener los días del mes y mostrar en formato dd/mm/aaaa en java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/140941/como-obtener-los-d%c3%adas-del-mes-y-mostrar-en-formato-dd-mm-aaaa-en-java)

Answer (score -1):

Para darle formato a una columna usa la propiedad converter como la que usas en la columna que te puese de ejemplo como lo utilice se muestra bien `pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"`

```
<p:column styleClass="columns">
<h:outputText value="#{detalle.horaEntrada}">
  <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
</h:outputText>
```

Tendiras que primero darle un formato a la fecha luego setter con la fecha nueva a la lista donde la muestras.

```
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

String fechaString= "05-03-2018 12:00";
Date date = inputFormat.parse(fechaString);
```

Comment: ya lo implemente pero me manda este error  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

Comment: Entonces guardas la fecha como string?

Comment: pues es que asi me lo arroja, me marca esto , Could not convert '[1, 3, 2018, 2, 3, 2018, 3, 3, 2018, ]' to a string.

Comment: Yo pregunto si guardas esta fecha como string en la base de datos?

Comment: no, esa fecha no la guardo, solo debo mostrar los dias del mes

Comment: Edite la respuesta para que le primero le des un formato a la fecha

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74069/discussion-between-raul-cacacho-and-root93).

Answer (score -1):

Espero haberte ayudado

```
//Aquí colocas tu objeto tipo Date
Date myDate = new Date();

//Aquí obtienes el formato que deseas
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(myDate));
```